# Why after i apply armature modifiers pose mode not working?

Tags: armature

1. I create model
2. I create armature
3. I paint weights
4. In pose mode model move with bones

When i apply armature modifiers (need to export model) in pose mode model not move with bones. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need to export the armature to?
In general, you dont need to apply the armature modifier to export to another software.
If you want to use the animations in other engines (for example UE), there is actually a lot you should pay attention to.
Worth watching would be
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdGkKbtQxE0&t=790s) and the following in the playlist.

Comment: if i not apply modifiers model curved after import https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259145/why-export-to-gltf-doesnt-work-correctly